# Annotation @ConditionalOnMissingBean not matching in test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two implementations of one interface - default and dev. I use `@ConditionalOnProperty` for default implementation and combination of `@Profile` and `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` for dev implementation.

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "keystore", value = "file")
public class DefaultKeyStoreService implements KeyStoreService {

@Service
@Profile("dev")
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(KeyStoreService.class)
public class DevKeyStoreService implements KeyStoreService {
```

Now, the problem is in test `DevKeyStoreServiceTest` for `DevKeyStoreService`.
I have configuration like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = {DevKeyStoreService.class},
    properties = {"keystore.file="}
)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class DevKeyStoreServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private DevKeyStoreService tested;

    @Test
    public void testPrivateKey() {
    } //... etc.
```

The result is:

```
Negative matches:
-----------------
DevKeyStoreService:
   Did not match:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: service.crypto.KeyStoreService; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'devKeyStoreService' (OnBeanCondition)
```

and the typical `org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'service.crypto.DevKeyStoreServiceTest'...`.

How can I configure the test class to be able to run it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

Annotation with value `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(KeyStoreService.class)` tries to find only concrete instances, which interface `KeyStoreService` is not. This way, it doesn't find anything.

When I use annotation with type instead, it works like a charm: `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(type = "KeyStoreService")`.

Comment: Even stranger - it doesn't work with fully qualified name either.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would to use the name option in @ConditionalOnMissingBean.

The problem you've got now it seems is that the Conditional is find itself and not the missing bean DefaultKeyStoreService.

If you do this

```
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name="defaultKeyStoreService")
```

It will probably work better.

The other option is to specifically have a prod profile to enable the prod bean.

What is interesting is that you can override beans when having a profile if you create those beans with xml.

So if you have in xml

```
<bean id="x" class="X"/>
```

And then have

```
<beans profile="dev">
  <bean id="x" class="Y"/>
</beans>
```

When you enable the dev profile it will replace the x bean in the unprofiled context with the bean x in the dev profile.

The same behaviour does not occur when using annotations however.

Right when profiles came out I logged a [bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9508) in this regard, it wasn't taken up.

Comment: Sadly, I can't use Conditional on name, because DefaultKeyStoreService is just default implementation and there could be others in application extension. I need to go against interface. An I cannot use non-dev profile because there could be dev environment to use standard keystore file with defined keys.

Comment: why don't use hang the prod bean against the prod profile?

Comment: There is no prod profile. We have many profiles combining together to be able to build specific application.

Comment: But then your last resort and I think it'll definitely work is to use @Condition and then create a condition class. In this condition class you can check the bean context to see if a KeyStoreManager is available and if not, create the dev one.

Comment: sorry, I meant @Conditional

Answer (score 1):

the type needs to be a **fully qualified name** otherwise the classloader will throw a `ClassNotFoundException` which causes the matching to fail. This behaves like the specified bean has not been found, but this condition will always inject `DevKeyStoreService` no matter a `KeyStoreService` exists or not.

A workaround that works for me is to ignore the implementation class:

```
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(value = KeyStoreService.class, ignored = DevKeyStoreService.class)
public class DevKeyStoreService implements KeyStoreService {
}
```